# Prevent App restart when revoking permission

Tags: android, react-native

When a User revokes the Location permission, the application restarts instead of resuming.

Is it possible to prevent this from happening?

One solution mentioned that a null check should resolve it, however that isn't the case.

```kotlin
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        SplashScreen.show(this)
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not possible - app architecture and lifecycles do not account for permissions being revoked at runtime. This has benefit of allowing apps to check for permission only once per launch and restart forces them to re-check permission.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to prevent this from happening?

No, sorry.

Since your app usually is in the background when this happens, and since your app's process can be terminated at any time while it is in the background, your app should already be handling this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding this on MainActivity.java:

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RNBootSplash.init(this);
    if (arePermissionsGranted()) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
      super.onCreate(null);
    }
  }
  
  private boolean arePermissionsGranted() {
    // Check for the required permissions
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
      int cameraPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
      int locationPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
      int notificationPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED);

      return cameraPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
              && locationPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
              && notificationPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```